# PayPal Subscription Payment Failed

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When a subscription payment fails, PayPal will retry for n times.

What transaction type (`subscr_cancel` or `subscr_eot`) is sent back via IPN, after all retries fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specifics depend on the PayPal product you're using, although the logic works similar(`ish) across both Website Payments Standard subscription buttons and Express Checkout Recurring Payments (via the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API):

This depends on whether you've set MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS or not. If MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS > 0 is set, it will cancel the subscription after n number of attempts and you'll receive a subscr_cancel. If you have it set to MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=0, you'll get recurring_payment_skipped and the recurring payment will be marked as having an outstanding balance. If you specify AUTOBILLOUTAMT=AutoBillAmt, the outstanding balance will be added to the next billing cycle.

I would suggest taking a look at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id091EB0901HT which lists all IPN variables, including the ones for recurring payments.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm using Website Payments Standard subscription buttons, which doesn't seem to have a MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS variable. Still unsure what transaction type will PayPal send after all failed retries.

Comment: For WPS this depends on the `sra` variable as per https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI00JQU once this has exhausted, it will cancel as per https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_subscribe_buttons#id08ADFC002A6

Comment: the urls in PayPal docs changed, the information is now here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADFC002A6 if I read it correctly, there is no option to change the number of retries in PayPal buttons (only on/off)

Comment: @PayPal_Robert Hey man, it's been a long time.. I can't seem to find any information on WPP_RP and what the payment retry schedule is.. any idea where I can find that?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal returns `subscr_failed` for this case, and the possible return values are:

```
subscr_signup: subscription sign-up.
subscr_cancel: subscription cancellation.
subscr_failed: subscription payment failure.
subscr_payment: subscription payment.
subscr_eot: subscription’s end-of-term.
subscr_modify: subscription modification.
```

Please [click here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/archive/PP_subscriptions.pdf) for further clarification.