# When is PayPal MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS set to No Limit?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

In the PayPal documentation for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API Operation, it specifies:

> MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS: (Optional) Number of scheduled payments that can fail before the profile is automatically suspended. An IPN message is sent to the merchant when the specified number of failed payments is reached.
>
> Character length and limitations: Number string representing an integer

However, it does not mention anything about what happens when you set the MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS to zero.

From this SO answer:
[PayPal Subscription Payment Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253891/paypal-subscription-payment-failed)

> If MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS > 0 is set, it will cancel the subscription
> after n number of attempts and you'll receive a subscr_cancel. If you
> have it set to MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=0, you'll get
> recurring_payment_skipped and the recurring payment will be marked as
> having an outstanding balance.

I believe that setting MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=0 will create an account with MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS showing as "No Limit." Can anyone confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Can downvote explain the reasoning? I'm asking for clarification of the PayPal API documentation that does not currently exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed that setting MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=0 will create an account with MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS showing as "No Limit" on PayPal. Setting MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=1  will trigger the IPN message "recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment" on the first failed payment.

Comment: Above is correct. But In my case when i was creating a recurring profile, I was trying to set max failed payments to a value of 3, but with constant param MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3, there was no error and it was not setting this value in Recurring Profile. But when I checked the examples in PayPal doc https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/, it was just MAXFAILPAYMENTS and not MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS. So by setting MAXFAILPAYMENTS=3, I was able to set this value in Recurring Profile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cancellation on payment failure. After the initial failure PayPal will try to take payment again after 5 days. If that also fails that PayPal will try a third and final time after a further 5 days.

When you can set up the original PayPal Profile you have two options for dealing with failed charges. This is found in the Recurring Charges section for the subscription on profile.

The terms you will get here like:

```
recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment
```

and this will also give you term for the retry date when next attempt is going to be execute.

```
'retry_at' => '02:00:00 Feb 08, 2017 PST',
```