# PayPal's Recurring Payments, Skipped will retry in 5 days time. How do I make it try now?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

So, if I am using PayPal for a subscription to a website/service/software and my payment skips because my card expired or there isn't enough funds.

How do I as a user make the payment try and get the money again after fixing my paypal/bank account without having to wait 3-5 days for it to try again?

Answer (score 1):

From a user point of view; based on [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Retry-Payment/td-p/1032907?profile.language=en) discussion I assume there is a bunch of hard-coded rules in PayPal and that is just one of them. It seams to me like this cannot be overridden by user. If you need to pay someone immediately, it might be worth doing it manually and then requesting a refund for future retry from PayPal.

From the developer point of view; [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/reattempt_failed_payment/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253891/paypal-subscription-payment-failed) might be helpful/related to the topic, but don't explicitly answer the question.